# Heavy, Wired Gaming Mouse

Tags: mice

I want a **heavy, wired** gaming mice. It need the following requirements:

1. Must be wired
2. Must be heavy (120g - 150g), having removable weights would be great
3. Must have at least 2 programmable buttons on the side
4. Must cost no more than CAD$90
5. Must be from a reputable brand (e.g. Logitech, Razer, Steelseries, etc.)
6. Must have lighting, preferably RGB
7. Must be big, around the size of the Logitech G602 or Razer Deathadder 2013

I would like recommendations, preferably with links to Canadian retailers (such as NCIX, Canada Computers, Memory Express, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The Corsair M65 PRO RGB meets your requirements(http://www.corsair.com/en/m65-pro-rgb-fps-gaming-mouse-black), points by points:
Wired, 168g with adjustable weights, 2 programming buttons on the side, around 65€ (in France), Corsair, RGB lightning, not that small but for you?

At NCIX: http://www.ncix.com/search/?qcatid=0&q=m65+pro